# Query table before refresh event not calling

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a query from a pervasive sql database and would like to write some code that should execute before the query table is refreshed.

I have put the following code in the `sheet1 object` where the table is located. This is just to see if I can get the before refresh event to work.

```
Private Sub querytable_beforerefresh(Cancel As Boolean)

MsgBox ("brace for update")

End Sub
```

Needless to say, When I refresh the query table I don't receive a msgbox, nor do I get a debug error.
Is there something else I need to do to use the beforerefresh event?

Comment: Recheck the name of the QueryTable object.  I'm guessing its 'QueryTable1' or something other than 'querytable'.  Then update the function name accordingly.